# how do I export matlab answers to excel?

Tags: excel, matlab, automation

I made simple calculator GUI in Matlab. How do I export each answer to excel in MATLAB? please help me..i already used xlswrite but it will just replace the answer in excel.. can you help me a code which export each answer to excel which is keep on adding answer

Code example:

```
a = get(handles.input1_gamma,'String'); %gamma 
b = get(handles.input2_h,'String'); %h 
c = get(handles.input3_q,'String'); %q 
d = get(handles.input4_power,'String'); %POWER 
% a and b are variables of Strings type, and need to be converted 
% to variables of Number type before they can be added together 
out = [str2num(a) * str2num(b)* str2num(c)]; 
e = {'Power','gamma','H','Q'; out,str2num(a),str2num(b),str2num(c)}; 
xlswrite('results.xls', e, 'Sheet1' , 'A1');
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  Please give an example of the code you're using.

Comment: i am using MATLAB.. i do have a GUI calculator.. i wanted to save each answer to excel using xlswrite.. the problem when i am using xlswrite it wont save each result on excel.. i wanted some1 to help me which will save each result being calculate in excel.. got me sir?

Comment: You've just said the same thing as in your question; it still doesn't make sense.  Please show an example of how you are using `xlswrite`.

Comment: Come on, guys, the question is clear. By you need to decide if you want to add new numbers based on a counter inside function (which means the numbers will be overwritten next time you run the GUI) or append them at the end of range of any existing file. In the later case you have to detect the working range, probably through ActiveX. Dealing with text file would be much easier.

Comment: what you mean I need to decide of what new numbers? how do i detect that working range? do you have any idea code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a functin as defined in your code xlswrite('results.xls', e, 'Sheet1' , 'A1');

Frohe Weihnachten from Germany

See also:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html

My suggestion:

```
function [ output_args ] = xlswrite( file , e , sheet,range)
%XLSWRITE Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


%open excel file with absolute path
file =[cd '\' file];
exlObject = actxserver('Excel.Application');
exlObject.visible = 1;
exlObject.Workbooks.Open(file);
exlWkbk = exlObject.Workbooks;

%save e to defined range
exlSheet1=exlObject.Sheets.Item(sheet);
dat_range=[range ':' range];
rngObj = exlSheet1.Range(dat_range);
rngObj.Value=e;

%save and close
exlObject.DisplayAlerts=0;
exlSheet1.SaveAs(file);
exlWkbk.Close;
exlObject.Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the output of your function to Excel with `xlsappend`, available on the [FileExchange site](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28600-xlsappend).

`xlsappend` will append the data by detecting the first unused row of an Excel worksheet, and paste the numeric (or cell) array.

```
[success,message] = xlsappend(file,data,sheet)
```